# Lightning - Related List

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, app-builder

In Lightning is there an analog to apex:relatedlist??

I'd like to build a custom component, visible in App builder, that simply displays a lightning designed related-list for a select related object.

With visualforce you could simply call

```
<apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />
```

I tried accomplishing this via a visualforce page and the visualforce standard lightning component but I don't get the lightning design.

Comment: You may find an answer here.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226178/can-you-include-a-related-list-in-a-lightning-component-similar-to-visualforce/245333#245333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lightning component that can only pull related list at this point .

Recommend using the SLDS design system and use Tabs ,Datatables and Related List Header to build your own custom component

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/#flavor-related-list

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/