# Can you include a related list in a lightning component similar to visualforce <apex:relatedList/>?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have been googling around and haven't found a way to show the history related list of an object inside a component.

Is it possible or would it have to be custom built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom related list for lightning. Maybe will be helpful 
https://github.com/artyom-bazyk/singleRelatedList

Answer (score 4):

There's **no** out of the box component available for displaying a related list on a custom lightning component. If you were building a standard record page, you could have done it using [Standard Lightning Page Related List Component](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_comp_related_list.htm).

In order to display a related list on a custom lightning component, you may rather like to use [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) and customize it to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If we are not able to show Related List in a component, might worth redirecting to them instead?

You can do that using `e.force:navigateToRelatedList`, just pass the relatedList Api name and get it going.

```
gotoRelatedList : function (component, event, helper) {
    var relatedListEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToRelatedList");
    relatedListEvent.setParams({
        "relatedListId": "Cases",
        "parentRecordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    relatedListEvent.fire();
}
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToRelatedList/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you want to include it/use it, for example, if you are using a [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) you can simply reference the api name of your field and it will automatically create a lookup field.

> **Usage Consideration**
>
> - The lookup type is supported in Lightning Experience only. When used in the mobile app, the lookup type is rendered as an input text
>     field.

That being said, if you want to add a lookup field elsewhere and not use the above component, you will most likely have to create a custom lightning component.

There are numerous resources online that provide code snippets on doing so.

The [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/) provides a markup skeleton for you to achieve this.

A quick search will also provide several references to blogs on how to create your own component.