# Create customized Record List in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to create a record list like below. When the user presses New button, there will be a pop up page with customized fill in page.

I tried to find any source code for RecordList but can't manage to find them. Is there any documentation on this for reference? Thanks in advance,
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you try to make a clone of the related list? where do you need it?
sorry for my english :D

Comment: Hi, I want to create a record table with different field names. It should be in Meters or Accounts tab. When the users open the page it should be in the first landing page

Comment: If you open an Object tab, the first thing you see is the list of all records created, just like the image you posted, else if you need a list of a relared object (for example the contacts of a single account), you can insert it in a record page, using the Lighting App Builder.

Comment: How can I change the column names of a ListView?

Comment: you need to change the field label, otherwise, if you only want to change the header, you need to make a custom component.

Comment: Is there any available aura component for Record List ?

Comment: unfortunely no. you can combine lightning-card, lightning-datatable and lightning-button for a similar result. You can look at this link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226178/can-you-include-a-related-list-in-a-lightning-component-similar-to-visualforce